# Парсинг - Woocommerce WebHook

Tags: woocommerce, google-apps-script

Прошу помочь разобраться с парсингом json'a через Google App Script

Google App Script - выглядит таким образом:

```
function doPost(request) {

  var content = JSON.parse(request.postData.contents);

  var row = [];
  for (var elem in content) {
    row.push(content[elem]);
  }

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET ID")
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  sheet.appendRow(row);

  var result = {"result":"ok"};

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

Но в таблице входящие данные выглядят так:

[image: json import]

что не есть читабельно.

Содержание запроса (из логов woocommerc'a)

```
{"order":{"id":240,"order_number":240,"order_key":"wc_order_5740128f34b30","created_at":"2016-05-22T10:46:13Z","updated_at":"2016-05-24T05:38:20Z","completed_at":"2016-05-24T04:38:20Z","status":"processing","currency":"UAH","total":"1499.00","subtotal":"1499.00","total_line_items_quantity":1,"total_tax":"0.00","total_shipping":"0.00","cart_tax":"0.00","shipping_tax":"0.00","total_discount":"0.00","shipping_methods":"u0411u0435u0441u043fu043bu0430u0442u043du0430u044f u0434u043eu0441u0442u0430u0432u043au0430","payment_details":{"method_id":"cod","method_title":"u041du0430u043bu043eu0436u0435u043du043du044bu0439 u043fu043bu0430u0442u0435u0436","paid":false},"billing_address":{"first_name":"Andrey","last_name":"XXX","company":"","address_1":"XXX60, kv 13","address_2":"","city":"Kiev","state":"","postcode":"","country":"UA","email":"xxx@gmail.com","phone":"674470023"},"shipping_address":{"first_name":"Andrey","last_name":"XXX","company":"","address_1":"XXX60, kv 13","address_2":"","city":"Kiev","state":"","postcode":"","country":"UA"},"note":"","customer_ip":"37.115.64.175","customer_user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36","customer_id":1,"view_order_url":"http://www.mysite.com.ua/my-account/view-order/240","line_items":[{"id":28,"subtotal":"1499.00","subtotal_tax":"0.00","total":"1499.00","total_tax":"0.00","price":"1499.00","quantity":1,"tax_class":null,"name":"u041du0430u0434u0443u0432u043du043eu0439 u0434u0438u0432u0430u043d "Air Lips" (u043au0440u0430u0441u043du044bu0439)","product_id":9,"sku":"","meta":[]}],"shipping_lines":[{"id":29,"method_id":"free_shipping","method_title":"u0411u0435u0441u043fu043bu0430u0442u043du0430u044f u0434u043eu0441u0442u0430u0432u043au0430","total":"0.00"}],"tax_lines":[],"fee_lines":[],"coupon_lines":[],"customer":{"id":1,"created_at":"2016-05-08T18:40:08Z","email":"xxx@gmail.com","first_name":"","last_name":"","username":"admin","role":"xxx","last_order_id":"240","last_order_date":"2016-05-22T10:46:13Z","orders_count":1,"total_spent":"1499.00","avatar_url":"http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/?s=96","billing_address":{"first_name":"Andrey","last_name":"XXX","company":"","address_1":"XXX60, kv 13","address_2":"","city":"Kiev","state":"","postcode":"","country":"UA","email":"xxx@gmail.com","phone":"674470023"},"shipping_address":{"first_name":"Andrey","last_name":"XXX","company":"","address_1":"XXX60, kv 13","address_2":"","city":"Kiev","state":"","postcode":"","country":"UA"}}}}
```

Заголовки:

user-agent: WooCommerce/2.5.5 Hookshot (WordPress/4.5.2)

content-type: application/json

x-wc-webhook-topic: order.updated

x-wc-webhook-resource: order

x-wc-webhook-event: updated

x-wc-webhook-signature: DRCgw7X10oB8H8I7wwvLyJql5LqumJHXyqIfi6KSWEU=

x-wc-webhook-id: 262

x-wc-webhook-delivery-id: 353

Метод : POST

Comment: Содержание запроса битое, json невалидный.

Comment: Это можно как-то исправить? это woocommerce его таким передает, без доп настроек...

Comment: Попробовал провалидировать через jsonlint. Показывает, что ошибки в тех местах где русские символы кодируются

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var content = JSON.parse(request.postData.contents)[0];`

или

`var content = JSON.parse(request.postData.contents)['order'];`

Если вы не знаете, что к вам точно придет, попробуйте определить значение

```
function doPost(request) {
  var result = {
    result: undefined
  };
  try {
    var content = JSON.parse(request.postData.contents);
    var row = [];
    if (content.hasOwnProperty('order')) {
      for (var elem in content['order']) {
        row.push(content['order'][elem]);
      }
    } else {
      row.push(request.postData.contents);
    }
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEET ID')
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    sheet.appendRow(row);
    result.result = 'ok';
  } catch (err) {
    result.result = 'err';
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

Comment: К сожалению - не исправило ситуацию. Все равно в таком же формате отображается в таблице.

Comment: @Qbeck, не ожидал, что исправит. Считайте это пингом. Приведите в вопросе содержимое `request.postData.contents`. Что там находится? Вероятно, что после `JSON.parse` получается массив. В остальном, ваш код для моих данных работает.

Comment: Добавил в описание. + ответ от в логах после отправки - HTTP 302 Moved Temporarily: Moved Temporarily Moved Temporarily The document has moved <a HREF="https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=Xq5WMdkDuDsYr7fU36HbNx1hFLuxR2niuDjmYYDKoq8koI5Nkizroa8udeMsdfJNhsJsFqblKrq9vLrKEK5DwQjAuU4NUrccm5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_1xSncGQajx_ryfhECjZEnJHETriXWy48reyEDwd_WmoeX2BioZ8_iQIVCPmJQfxL7xPZRIm2WNEriAQDvf2J9KOIp7sEUsJ2&lib=MELPAFc8AyKS_AnmylvFhpEp7lTnrkX4I" rel="nofollow">here</A>.

Comment: @Qbeck, у вас все работает нормально и правильно. Приложение добавляет запись из одного элемента `{order:{}}` Поправил свое решение.

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Помогли... Работает